Manually add a keyboard command to Thunderbird menu?
I just want to add one keyboard command to the "Find and Replace..." menu option.
⌘-SHIFT-F
None of the add-ons seem to be able to do this.
Is there a config file or some other way to add this keyboard command?


There is a Thunderbird add-on that has some support for creating custom shortcuts, named tbkeys-lite. It supports, as of 2024-09-20, Thunderbird versions 115.* through 130.*. While I'm technically running on 131.*, I was able to tweak the XPI file to fib about it supporting version 131.* (the present beta), and it installed fine. Assuming you are running an "officially supported" version of Thunderbird, then tbkeys-lite should show up upon searching for it inside Thunderbird (Tools > Add-Ons and Themes, search "tbkeys-lite" in the "Find more add-ons" search box, then install it).
I was then able to set the following settings for the add-on (Tools > Add-ons and Themes, select tbkeys-lite, click Preferences tab):
Main key bindings (by default, this has bindings that try to mimic Gmail bindings; I didn't care for that so I removed those entries):
{
}

Compose key bindings:
{
  "command+shift+t": "cmd:cmd_findReplace"
}

At which point, in the compose window, "command+shift+t" opened up the find-replace dialog (so long as the main message window had focus, and not something like the To or From fields).
Snapshot of settings:

Screencast demo
Note: the documentation for this add-on is sparse, but there is a README.md on the add-on's GitHub page.

Thanks for the quick response. This works. However, I noticed that keyboard shortcuts do not get added to the dropdown menu. Why would this be? (see image added to initial question)

I suspect they are not added to the dropdown menu because there is no API exposed by Thunderbird for add-ons to use in order to manipulate the menu content.
